# Pronunciation of Bonne journée

Tags: prononciation, phonétique

I would like to clear up a question I have about the pronunciation of 'j' in the phrase 'bonne journée' in French. Up until recently, I just assumed it was pronounced identically to how 'j' is normally pronounced in french (/ʒ/), as in 'bonjour'. But lately I have been hearing something close to the pronunciation of j as in English or Italian.

The example in Forvo sounds like a /j/ : [Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/word/bonne_journ%C3%A9e/)

In the following link the phonetic transcription also seems to use /j/

> /bɔn juʁ.ne/

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bonne_journ%C3%A9e)

If this is true, then what is the reason for this departure from the usual pronunction? Or is it just an artifact due to fast speaking. I don't want to sound like I'm splitting hairs; I'm just really curious. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: You can also compare with this one (mousewheel-click it) : [*Bonne journée*](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=bonne%20journ%C3%A9e). Pronunciation is good, maybe slightly slower than usual.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Yes, here I can here the /ʒ/ more clearly. However in real life I here French people say something more akin to /j/

Comment: @Arun I'm afraid you are confusing IPA /j/ and /d͡ʒ/.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, “j” alone is always /ʒ/ in French (even though indeed fast pronunciation can twist it a bit). Fixed English page of Wiktionary, [French one](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bonne_journ%C3%A9e) had the right IPA.

Answer (score 7):

The sound you transcript as "j" en English and Italian is a [voiced palato-alveolar affricate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_palato-alveolar_affricate) transcripted in IPA as /d͡ʒ/. This sound exists in French when the "j" followed a "d" like in *a**dj**oindre*. It is very different from the incorrectly reported /j/ sound which would mean something like *Bonne yournée* like with a Spanish accent.

When the letter "j" appears at the beginning of a French word, it is pronounced as /ʒ/ alone. Many foreign words commonly used in French like the first names "Johnny" and "Jamel" and city names like "Jakarta" are pronounced with a starting /d͡ʒ/. This is never the case with *journée*.

On the other hand, the ending "e" in *Bonne* is usually mute in French, outside southern accents. That means when *bonne journée* is pronounced quickly like it is the case when used like "have a nice day", *journée*'s "j" is not alone but compounded with the previous consonant "nj" making /bɔnʒuʁ.ne/. It is well possible that we (French speakers)  unconsciously insert a /d/ to ease the transition between the /n/ and the /ʒ/ leading to  /bɔnd͡ʒuʁ.ne/.

Comment: In real life - as in super markets and so on - I almost hear people saying bonne djornee, which is what set off this whole thing. But as you say it's just a result of fast pronunciation